# Replacing Nested If Statements in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to generate a pattern reader where I input a string of numbers and check if it is a valid pattern of mine. My pattern involves checking if the values follow something like
val0 > val1 <= val2 > val3 and so on.

```
        if loc0 > loc1: 
                 if loc2 > loc3:
            if loc4 > loc5:
                if loc5 <= loc6:
                    append to list
            if loc3<=loc4:
                if loc4<=loc5:
                    if loc5<=loc6:
                        append to list`
```

Currently to check this I have a lot of if statements and would like to avoid doing so to make my program more robust and error proof.
How can I avoid doing so?

Comment: I would argue that this solution might be more readable and easy-to-follow than some other solutions. Of course I don't see your full code, but are you sure you need to refactor this?

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on compound comparisons?  We expect you to do that before posting here.

Comment: @smuuf I should have added this to the description, but I eventually need this to accept strings of any length and the patterns will keep growing with more and more comparison checks needed to ensure its a valid pattern.

Comment: @Prune I did, but that's not my problem. I know I can make compound comparisons with this, but I need to expand this eventually to take in any string length, but the amount of comparison checks will grow to ensure its a valid pattern. I'm looking more for an iterative approach here and have struggled.

Comment: An iterative approach to *what*?  You haven't specified your program objective.  "A valid string of mine" gives us *no* idea what you're trying to do: the only clear problem you presented was how to reduce the nesting of that particular `if` tree.  Solving some more general problem would be too broad, as you have not yet made an attack of your own.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

you can do all in one line as(complete the pattern):

```
if val0 > val1 <= val2 > val3:
    append to list
```

Comment: I'd generally recommend *against* chaining comparisons in different directions (e.g. `val0 > val1 <= val2`) even if that's valid for the test being performed. That's not how inequalities work in mathematics, so it tends to be confusing. Using explicit `and` or `or` expressions is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Representing your string as a list of numbers since it would be ambiguous to represent non-single digit numbers in a string without a separator.
Once you do that you can go forward with the below solution.

```
string = []
answer = True
for i in range(1,len(string),2):
    if not(string[i]<string[i-1] and string[i] <=string[i+1]):
        answer = False
        break
return answer
```

Explanation : Third argument of range is a step function. For clarity :

```
list( range(0,20,3))
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```